# Help! Sub-URI for Passenger with Apache 2 does not work!

Tags: apache2, redmine, passenger

I am trying to setup Redmine 1.1.3 application on my Ubuntu 8.04 with Apache2 and Passenger 3.0.7.
I have verified that my installation of Redmine is working properly by running Webrick as web server. As I have read that it is not the recommended webserver for Production, I have decided to host it using Apache 2.

I am planning to configure the Apache webserver to support sub-URI, with reference to the guide: http://www.modrails.org/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri.
However, I am having some problem with the configuration of the Apache2's config file called "default" in the "sites-available" folder.

Below is my configuration in the "default" file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    **DocumentRoot /var/www**
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
       <Directory /var/www/redmine>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
       </Directory>
       RailsBaseURI /redmine
       RailsEnv production

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration has returned with a "no such file to load -- /var/www/config/environment" error, after accessing Redmine via "http"//www.mydomain.com/redmine".

This error is only overcome if I change the **"Document Root" to "/usr/local/redmine-1.1.3/public"**, which is where the Redmine application codes is located.

Note:
1. I have already created the symlink in "/var/www/redmine" as described in the guide.
2. I have also "chown" the entire "redmine-1.1.3" folders and files (recursively) to "www-data".

I will appreciate if anyone can help me to configure my setup correctly as I really hope to make use of the sub-URI approach, so that I can maintain the use of a common port "80" for multiple applications.

Thank you in advance.

Cheers,

### Kevin

Comment: Hi Stoic, I suppose your RVM = "Ruby Version Manager"? No, I am not.. or rather I don't think so..

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup working on Mac. Mine is setup without Virtual Hosts since I wanted to keep some php apps running and Passenger was interfering with those if enabled for the entire site.

I have two setup files included from my apache httpd.conf file:

1. passenger.conf

   ```
   LoadModule passenger_module /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.7/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.7
   PassengerRuby /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
   PassengerEnabled Off
   ```
2. redmine.conf

   ```
   <Location "/redmine">
       Options Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       AllowOverride all

       PassengerEnabled On
       RailsBaseURI /redmine
       RailsEnv production

   </Location>
   ```

My system is Mac so the paths might be different, but I have it set up with a symlink in my docroot pointing to my redmine's public directory.

Perhaps the "RailsBaseURI" will be the key to getting it working for you.

Comment: Hi Matt, I believe it has to be a configuration issue too, as it will work only when I set the "Document Root" to "/usr/local/redmine-1.1.3/public", which will defeat the purpose of me trying to use sub-URI. Any other suggestions are most welcome..

Comment: Perhaps it's because your Directory entry is for /var/www/redmine - which is really a symlink - try replacing that path with the destination of the symlink, or using a <Location "/redmine"> section instead of a <Directory> one.

Comment: @matt-connolly : Tried both methods as suggested. But the result is still the same as my original configuration, ie. "no such file to load -- /var/www/config/environment".. I'm stuck.. :(

Comment: Thank you so much, i didn't even think of turning on or off Passenger for certain urls. Now my setup works as a charm and i know this is offtopic :P `symlink in my docroot pointing to my redmine's public directory.` public dir is very important here, otherwise i got the same error.